# Load html file with video in webview from assest folder in andorid

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, webview

I'm trying to show the html file with video from assest folder, video should play automatically when user start the app, please check the html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body> 

<video width="400" autoplay>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>
Video courtesy of 

</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

Now i am trying to play this html file in webview using loadUrl and loadDataWithBaseURL but video is not starting,
  Working on android api 19(Kitkat) i read in WebViewClient library from 4.4 version shouldOverrideUrlLoading method won't call if we load content from assest folder. I tried using the badurl to fix it but no result.

I am working on this issue from past 10 days and new to android development please help me how to start the video on starting the android app.

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, are you able to share them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep html files and test.mp4 video on same hierarchy. And also add this js script on head

```
var vid=document.getElementById('video');
vid.addEventListener("loadstart", showVideo, false);
function showVideo(e) {
  vid.play();
}
```